# error: conflicting types for 'exit' in OS header 'proc.h'

Tags: c, linux, header, proc

I am a newbie to C/Pro*C
I compile a C code in Linux. I get the following error.

```
/usr/include/sys/proc.h:560: error: conflicting types for 'exit'
/usr/include/sys/proc.h:560: error: conflicting types for 'exit'
```

In proc.h, exit function is defined as

```
extern void exit(int, int);
```

The header proc.h is an OS defined header and I have no idea why I get this error.

Comment: The exit() from libc / stdlib.h takes one int argument. The proc.h header's author should have known this.

Comment: What's the code you're trying to compile? Are you writing a device driver?

Answer (score 0):

If there is a conflicting type, it is as well defined elsewhere, probably with a different type - either as a function with a different signature, or as a variable.

Check if this is the case, and if so, rename your variable.